# SetObjectProperty: how to create inline objects

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ampscript, api, cloudpage

I have the following 'To' object in an API request:

```
"To": {
        "Address": "email address here",
        "SubscriberKey": "Subscriber key here",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "EmailAddress":"Email address here",
                "SubscriberKey": "Subscriber key here",
                "Language": "Language here",
                "Country": "Country here"
            }
        }
    }
```

What I am wondering is; how can I add values to the inline objects "ContactAttributes" and "SubscriberAttributes" with AMPscript?

I know that I can set values for the 'To' object with the SetObjectProperty function:

```
 SET @ts_to = CreateObject("To")
    SetObjectProperty(@ts_to, "Address", @EmailAddress)
    SetObjectProperty(@ts_to, "SubscriberKey", @SubscriberKey)
```

But I get stuck with these inline objects.

Answer (score 0):

Only *Address* and *SubscriberKey* are required, the rest go under *SubscriberAttributes*.  The *SubscriberAttributes* node should not include the Email Address or Subscriber Key.

```
{
    "To": {
        "Address": "aspriggs@example.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "aspriggs@example.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "FirstName": "Adam",
                "LastName": "Spriggs",
                "someCode": "1234",
                "HTML__payload": "<h1>Whee!</h1>"
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

The *SubscriberAttributes* values correspond to the column names in your Triggered Send Data Extension columns.

**Reference**

- [REST messageDefinitionSends](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSends.htm)